# How do I stop repeating labels in my pine script on Trading View?

Tags: pine-script

Please see image example below, my plots are as follows:

`plotshape(Long, title="entry", text="Buy ⇡", textcolor=color.green, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.black, transp=0, size=size.small, offset=0)`

`plotshape(Short, title="exit", text="Sell ⇣", textcolor=color.red, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.black, transp=0, size=size.small, offset=0)`

I only need to display the first instance of each label, would like my alerts to only trigger on those as well but cannot for the life of me figure out why they are duplicating! Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

```
long1  = ta.barssince(Open > Close )
long2  = ta.barssince(Open < Close )[1]
short1 = ta.barssince(Open > Close )[1]
short2 = ta.barssince(Open < Close )
sell = short1>short2  ? close: na
buy =long1<long2  ? close: na
plotshape(sell, title="Sell", text="S", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white)
plotshape(buy, title="Buy", text="B", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).